# What is the maximum amount of RAM a 2011 MacBook Pro can utilize?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, upgrade, memory

I know macs can be picky about how much their max memory capacity is, so what is the maximum RAM I can install in my two available memory slots?

Model:  Early 2011 MacBook Pro 13-inch 2.3GHz dual-core Intel Core i5

[image]

[image]

Can I put in 16GB with 8GB in each slot?

**According to the [Apple support](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP619?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), my specific model can officialy take 8gb, 4 on each slot. But many people say that we can put double the official, is this true?**

---

**EDIT: It works, and I wrote an article about this whole process [here](http://themillibit.com/2017/09/19/how-to-speed-up-your-computer/) **

[image: HELL YEAH!]

Comment: do you know if it is possible to go to 32Gb ? And if 2400 Mhz works ?

Comment: I don't know anything about the Max limit for computing speed, but I do know that 32gb won't work

Comment: I highly recommend upgrading ram though, it does wonders @clemlaflemme

Comment: @RuchirBaronia - Why your blog's post is not available anymore? Was deleted or has a new URL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.You can install and use 16GB of RAM in that machine. There are several discussions in Apple's forum on this subject.

I Have same same model MBP and upgraded two weeks ago. Works great.

[image]

**Edit:** <sub>(as to the comments)</sub>

[This is](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01C7YY4BW) the product I have purchased to my mac. Please, before you buy make sure that the memory fit your specific mac model. Apple  do have a good webpage of [How to identify my mac model](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201608).

Here, you can find a [similar discussion](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/97664/Can+I+insert+16Gb+RAM+into+MacBook+Pro+early+2011) in iFixit forum

In my original answer I have mentioned SSD. Thanks to @tubedogg clarification, the SSD and RAM are unrelated in this discussion. Yet, when upgrading considering to upgrade the SSD is not a bad idea. 
Sorry for the bad analogy: it is like replacing parts in your car that will make it runs great, but it takes 15 minutes to start it.
For me, I decided to start with RAM. Upgrading the Hard Drive, made it even better.

I didn't see the Mac going over 8MB yet, so I opened every application on my mac just to get to 51%. Since the update it usually runs between 30%-45% of RAM used.

Which brings me to the following conclusion:

- **Can** You install 16MB RAM? Yes
- Do you **need** it? depends on your usage
- Why would you still install it? Upgrade once, even if you don't use it right away
- Should you also upgrade your hard drive? If you have the resources (money, time, transfer method), then yes

Comment: Hey Idan, thanks for your help. According to [this link](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP619?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) the official support for my model is only 8gb, so would it work to put in 16 gb? If so, then why isn't the official support just 16 gb?

Comment: I am not really sure, but my guess is the available technology at the time. Also, the whole SSD thing, I think that 16GB is not really used without it.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Right now I just have a normal hard drive. Why do you say the 16GB is not worth it without SSD?

Comment: I had the same conflict. Since that 8GBx2 was available for sale, and the price different was not significant, I decided to go for 16GB. I didn't bother with the research about the normal drive vs SSD, but it seems that you would not enjoy the 16GB without the SSD.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. An SSD will make loading data from storage faster. Increasing RAM will increase what can be kept in memory without having to read it again from storage or swapping to and from storage. Switching to an SSD should increase the overall performance of the machine, but SSD and RAM are essentially unrelated for purposes of this discussion, and certainly one is not needed for the other to function.

Comment: @tubedogg Ok. Thanks for the clarifications. Something I read two weeks ago and didn't bother research. Updated my post.

Comment: Hmm: it's a fact that it is absolutely pointless even worrying about the ram, at all, until you have an SSD.  If you have an ancient historic computer that has one of the archaic platter drives, you have to upgrade to a $50 SSD.  the performance increase from SSD totally overwhelms any performance increase from ram issues.  Sure, this question at hand is about ram, not drive.

Comment: Apple don't care much for old models, so after the initial "This is what we support" has been finished they don't come back to it.

Comment: @idan much memory is still very useful because OS X utilizes the unused parts as disk buffers, but it takes longer to fill them.  An SSD is such a great upgrade that if you have the choice between upgrading to SSD and more memory, go for the SSD.  I had a Windows computer which took so long to boot because of competing large startup programs that it was essentially useless for 5-10 minutes.,  Changing to SSD essentially made this go away without modifying the startup programs

Comment: @ Thorbjørn I agree with both statements. The 16GB is available in the market and for the price it seems silly to go for 8GB. As far as the HD, yes, if the computer is lagging, to replace just the memory might not be sufficient. I did replaced both. After replacing both the mac is pretty sweet again, not bad for 6 years old computer.

Comment: ordered PC3-10600 memory (amazon.com/gp/product/B01C7YYR4Q/…) and it was too big to fit in my mac. I will now have to return it. Why was it too large (it was double the size it should have been?)

Comment: @RuchirBaronia I'm sorry to hear that. Try and return your product. I have edited my answer with more details, including the Amazon link to the memory I bought. I also put a warning to others that read this.

Comment: @Idan, The three links you have in your answer are broken!

Comment: Edited. All links are tested to work. Feel free to [edit]

Comment: @Idan, The link you have for the RAM **is not compatible** with the MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011)!

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks! Sorry about that it was straight out my amazon purchase page. I have installed it and its working, but I **know** that I got the early 2011 one. Edited again.

Comment: @Idan thanks for answer - Why your RAM is based on `1067` MHz and in the original post is `1333` MHz? - Theoretically the latter is faster, right?

Answer (score 4):

According to [Everymac.com](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.3-13-early-2011-unibody-thunderbolt-specs.html) your particular model can support up to 16GB of RAM<sup>1</sup>

So, as to your question, "Can I put in 16GB with 8GB in each slot?"

**Yes.  That's exactly how you can upgrade your memory to 16GB.**  You will need one "16GB kit" which is two 8GB modules of [PC3-10600 memory](http://radnex.us/Crucial-PC3-10600-16GB-Kit-Mac).

---

<sup>1</sup> [Everymac.com](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.3-13-early-2011-unibody-thunderbolt-specs.html):  *Apple officially supports a maximum of 8 GB of RAM, but as first confirmed by site sponsor OWC, this model actually is capable of using up to 16 GB of RAM with two 8 GB memory modules.*

Comment: What do you mean "too big;"  physically?

Comment: Yes, physically. It can't physically fit in the slot, because it is double the size I need...

Comment: The link you provided is completely wrong.  The link in my answer "PC3-10600" is the product you need.  It's the very last line.

Answer (score 3):

While Apple Tech Specs states 8 GB RAM, nonetheless, yes you can use 16 GB RAM.

Here are two examples of supported RAM for your model.

- [Crucial 16GB Kit (2 x 8GB) DDR3L-1333 SODIMM Memory for Mac](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/macbook-pro-%2813-inch%2C-early-2011%29/CT3373717)
- [OWC Upgrades for MacBook Pro 2011](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/memory/Apple_MacBook_MacBook_Pro/Upgrade/DDR3_1333MHz_SDRAM)

Comment: ordered PC3-10600 memory (amazon.com/gp/product/B01C7YYR4Q/…) and it was too big to fit in my mac. I will now have to return it. Why was it too large (it was double the size it should have been?) –

Comment: @Ruchir Baronia, I didn't tell you to buy that! What you purchased states it's for a Mac Pro MacPro5,1 Mid 2012 and a Mid 2010 Mac Pro. If you'd followed the links I provided, you see that they are SODIMM (small outline dual in-line memory module) not DIMM (dual in-line memory module) and state compatible with MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011) not Mac Pros!

Comment: I'm sorry. Will this model work? https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B008LTBJK2/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: @Ruchir Baronia, Unless it states it compatible with a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011) then I would not purchase it! The two links I've already provided state compatibility with a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011), so I'd order from one of them! As to whether or not the one you've linked to will work or not I'd have to say no because the Crucial Part Numbers shown do not match what Crucial states to be compatible with a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011) like the one in my answer. The reason you need it to state it compatible is because 16GB is not Apple supported in your MBP.

Answer (score 0):

If you press the Memory upgrade information button in that window, it would take you to an Apple page stating the maximum memory is (I think) 8 GB, 4GB per slot. I have a Late 2011 13" MBP which I upgraded to 8 GB of RAM and it works fine.

However, I have heard of people who went past the max and put in 16 GB of RAM and it worked out. It's not officially supported though so it might not work or it might not work properly. You can always try it if you really need the RAM and are feeling adventurous.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgraded my MacBook Pro Late 2011 with 2.4 i5. PNY 2x8GB 1600mHz from Best Buy for $74. System profiler shows 1600 too. So I'm guessing it didn't down clock it to 1333 like it was originally with the 2x2GB modules.